#  sql consult in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a form in my  personalize HTML module in joomla

```
<form id="search-restaurant" class="form-a" action="find.php">
<div>
   ......
</div>
<div class="encuentra-tastepoint-submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
```

When I click on Submit button I want to execute a sql query in my data base and return the value in other page.

Where I have to put muy find.php file.

There is a manual or tutorial to do that in joomla 2.5

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `find.php` is the file that contains the code for the SQL queries in which case, you can keep it in the root of the module folder (in the same location as the module.xml).

You will also need to add `require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/'.'find.php' );` to `your_module.php`.